# Issue where disk space is not cleared after using docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

```
 Host distribution and version :  Windows Server 2016 LTS    
 Docker Version  :  Docker version 17.06.2-ee-10, build 66261a0
```

**Background :** We deployed some  springboot application using docker EE in Windows server 2016. Whenever we do an version upgrade of the application, the disk space is not cleared.
Over a period of time, the system complains of low disk space due to this issue.
Surprisingly I don't see this issue on linux version of docker.

I used the image prune command and also removed exited containers.
I removed dangling images as well using this command

```
docker rmi $(docker images --filter “dangling=true” -q *--no-trunc)
```

#### Actual behavior

The disk space is not freedup and I have to manually run this command to delete all contents in C:\Programdata\docker

```
robocopy C:\PURGE C:\ProgramData\Docker /PURGE
```

Steps

1. Pull images
2. Start containers
3. Stop Containers
4. Delete images using docker rmi containerid

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to [prune everything](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/#prune-everything)?

Comment: The command you use only remove `dangling` images, if you want to remove all images you need to use either prune above or `docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)`

Comment: Yes I tried 
1) Remove containers that are exited
docker rm $(docker ps -a -f status=exited -q)
2)Remove all docker Images
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
3) Docker System Prune to remove images,containers,networks
docker system prune -f

This issue happens mostly in Dev,Test environments where we keep updating new version images frequently.